# Running Stored Procedure multiple times concurrently

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssis

How can i run the same stored procedure multiple times with different set of parameter values and  with out waiting for the first execution to finish.

Example:

if i got proc sp_loaddatafrom @sourceId, @containerId

```
Execution - 1st:  exec sp_loaddatafrom 100001, 36
Execution - 2nd:  exec sp_loaddatafrom 100008, 92
Execution - 3rd:  exec sp_loaddatafrom 100005, 112
```

I want all to run concurrently.

How can this be achieved either in T-SQL / SSIS / C#

Comment: If at all possible, it would be better to modify the stored procedure to accept a [Table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb510489.aspx) - so it could run a set-based query that produces all of the results - and SQL Server can appropriately optimize this process.

Comment: Also, you should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix for stored procedures. It's only meant to be used by Microsoft, and it has special (sometimes undesirable) behaviour built in (specifically, SQL Server will always try to find such procedures in `master` before searching the current database - so if MS add a new one that conflicts with your chosen name, the MS one will be used)

Comment: Additionally I would personally use an ORM, unless there are side effects in this query.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing about sp_, Yes am aware of it and am not sure how i missed in my question to not have it there :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to .net 4.5 I would use the following code.

```
var results = Task.WhenAll(
    Task.Run(() => RunStoredProc(1)),
    Task.Run(() => RunStoredProc(2)),
    Task.Run(() => RunStoredProc(3))
).Result;
```

If I only have .net 4.0 I would use the TPL. A bit more cumbersome, still much nicer than the background worker.

```
var arguments = new []{1,2,3};

var results = from x in arguments.AsParallel()
              select RunStoredProc(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you will use C#, you can use 3 BackgroundWorkers calling the said stored procedure on its Do_Work event

Comment: I would only use BackgroundWorkers IFF I only have access to .net <= 3.5

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in SSIS by using 3 different `Execute SQL Task` which are not connected to each other .

[image]

By default SSIS uses `Serializable` option for `Isolation Level` which locks the entire data being read and keeps the lock till the transaction is complete. So in order to run the queries parallel you need to change the `Isolation level` to `Snapshot` which basically uses `NOLOCK` on data when it is read.

Update :-

Since the number of  `stored procedures` being executed is `dynamically` obtained then you need to create the package `programitically`

```
public void CreatePackage()
{
  Package package= new Package();
  ConnectionManager sqlConnection = GetSQLConnection(package,
                                    "localhost", "Database Name");
  TaskHost taskHost=null;
   for(int i=0;i<GetNoOfRowFromSQL();i++)
    {
      CreateDynamicTask(package);
    }
  package.Execute();
}

public void CreateDynamicTask(package Package)
{

      //Add the Execute SQL Task
      package.Executables.Add("STOCK:SQLTask");
       taskHost = package.Executables[0] as TaskHost;
      taskHost.Properties["SqlStatementSource"].SetValue(taskHost, 
                                            "EXECUTE Stored Proc);
     //Setting the Isolation Level
     taskHost.Properties["IsolationLevel"].SetValue(taskHost, 1048576);
     //the number signify 1048576 =Serializable
    }
}
```

Comment: this is always not just three time to call the procedure;  my parameter values comes from table and the no. of time stored procedure to be executed depends on the number of row from the parameter value table.

Comment: But instead of going into hazzles of creating SSIS package using C# ,i prefer using TPL`System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.Invoke(() => { CallSP1(); }, () => { CallSP12(); }, () => { CallSP3(); } );`